# Avoiding a possible table reference error

Tags: database-design, oracle-11g-r2

I'm working on a project that's due in 2 weeks and have hit a possibly serious roadblock. The app that I'm working on is some tuition reimbursement management system, whose use cases are dependent on the roles of the employee (user) trying to access it. It's a solo project, in which I was given a two-page document of some high-level requirements, involving the employee, the direct supervisor, the department head, and the benefits coordinator.

After a week of trying to plan it, and work on it, I came up with this: the `employees` table has a foreign key to itself called `manager_id` (an employee is a base user, then, iff there are no records such that `manager_id` equals that employee's `employee_id`), and a `department_roles_id` that points to the `department_roles` table that has a department and a `department_role_name`. Here's a screenshot of my ERD for this[image]

This approach, however, seems to have a problem. What happens when someone inserts an employee record into `employees`, with the same `department_role_id` as another record, but they have two different `manager_id`s (for example, if one of them was a manager of that department but the other one wasn't)? How to avert this?

NOTE: if it helps any, I'm on Oracle 11g.

Comment: I hope my commenting this doesn't turn this into an XY problem, but I thought of creating a trigger, `BEFORE INSERT ON employees`, that would check the `manager_id`,`department_role_id` of the employee against all the others, and if there's the same `department_role_id` but different `manager_id`, throw exception. This approach seems a bit tacky, however...

Comment: To clarify: an `employee` has a manager (another `employee`) and a `department_role`. Their `department` is determined by their `department_role`. Now, you seem to indicate that everyone with `department_role` "X" must have the same manager. If that's true, then `manager_id` should be in `department_role`, not in `employee`, because `department_role` would determine who someone's manager is.

Comment: Also - If `employee` contains everyone in the company, and everyone is linked to their boss (up to the company CEO/president/whatever), then either everyone is in the same department, or some people must have a boss from a different department. (e.g.: CIO is top manager of IT department; CFO is top manager of finance dept.; CEO is manager of both CIO and CFO).

Comment: Wouldn't moving `employees.manager_id` to `department_role` and having the employees reference that be a circular reference, though?

Comment: Logically, no more circular than `employees` to itself; however, you may well be right that Oracle might not let you do this. I was addressing the logical aspect first, and checking to be sure this is what you wanted. It seemed a little odd; my organization is relatively large, and there can be enough people doing the same basic task that more than one manager in a given department, dealing with people performing the same roles, is possible. If this is what you want, then determining how to make it work (break the normalization?) would be the next step.

Comment: I just talked to the trainer. Turns out the requirements weren't as strict as I was making them out to be. My design should be fine for now

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, it sounds like every `department_role` will belong to one and only one manager (but a single manager could manage multiple department roles).

If this is the case, then the database design should enforce it; `department_role` should include the column `manager_id`, a foreign key to the `employee` table.

And, if that's true, and every `employee` with a manager has a `department_role` as well, then including `manager_id` in `employee` would be denormalizing the database; you'd have to keep the `employee`.`manager_id` in sync with the `department_role`.`manager_id`. Since you could identify the manager based on the `department_role_id`, `manager_id` shouldn't be in `employee`.

You brought up the concern that this would be an illegal reference in Oracle. I located a [StackOverflow Q & A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18832586/3093192) that addressed this.

Their solution is:

- Create the table without the constraint first
- Optionally, "prime the pump" by manually inserting managers and database roles before adding the constraints.
- Create the constraints next (before inserting any data), using `ALTER TABLE ... ADD CONSTRAINT ...`.
- If at some point you find that you can't add a manager because a department role doesn't exist, and you can't add the role because the manager doesn't exist, you can use the following to get around it:

  ```
  ALTER SESSION SET CONSTRAINTS = DEFERRED;
  insert into emloyee (<column_list>) values (<value_list>);
  insert into department_role (<column_list>) values (<value_list>);
  commit;
  ```

  That said, given your set-up, I don't think you'll need to (unless someone is explicitly given a `department_role` that they manage, meaning they manage themselves, which seems unlikely).

NOTE: Logically, the top person in the organization will not have a manager, and may or may not have a department role, so your constraint must allow for that (either an `employee` with no `department_role_id`, or a `department_role` with no `manager_id`). For example, either the company CEO has no `department_role` listed, or the `department_role` of "CEO" would have no manager listed.